# pandas dtype period [Q-DEC] changes to object

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a `df` with one dtype `period[Q-DEC]` column.

```
Column    Non-Null Count  Dtype        
---  ------    --------------  -----        
 0   CIK       7436 non-null   int64        
 1   LINKDATE  7436 non-null   period[Q-DEC]
```

Grouping the `df` as

```
df.sort_values(['CIK','LINKDATE']).groupby(['LINKDATE','CIK'],as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[-1]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

turns `LINKDATE` into an `object`. How can I change the object back to `period[Q-DEC]`. I have tried `pd.to_datetime(df['LINKDATE'])` but I get this error:

> `TypeError: <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.period.Period'> is not convertible to datetime`

**UPDATE:** I need to convert the object to string format using `strftime('%FQ%q')`, then to `period[Q-DEC]` using `pd.to_datetime(df.LINKDATE).to_period("Q")`